# Can sendOrderedBroadcast be used between non-system apps?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to **allow a bunch of my apps to excange very small bits of data** not requiring user interacion. For this reason I am not starting Activities.

To acheve this I am testing sendOrderedBroadcast() as it allows specifyng a result receiver while broadcasing explicit intents towards a BroadcastReceiver regisetered in app Manifest.

The evidence seems to suggest **sendOrderedBroadcast() works** just either:

- inside an application
- when is triggered by System (in that case non-system apps can receive it)

***but IS BLOCKED between non-system Apps***.

Can anyone confirm or point me to some example of a working implementation between apps?